# Stm32f4 counting pulses (How can I adjust the rising edge voltage ?)

Tags: timer, stm32, stm32f4discovery

At the moment I use TIM2 on the stm32f4 - Discovery Board to count pulses (rising edges). How can I adjust the thresholds for the rising edges ? I want to count 1 V pulses. At the moment it is just possible to count 2V pulses. I'm not able to find something about this in the documentation.

Here is the code of my timer function.

```
void timer_2_pulse_counter_gpioa1_Init(){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= 0x01; // 1: IO port A clock enabled
    //RCC->AHB1ENR |= 0x10; // 1: IO port E clock enabled

    // APB1 peripheral reset register
    RCC->APB1ENR |= 0x01; // 1: enable TIM2

    // GPIO port mode register (GPIOx_MODER)
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x00000008; // 10: Alternate function mode PA1 => AF mode
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x00000010; // 1000: Must refer to AF1 (alternate function for TIM1/ TIm2)
    GPIOA->PUPDR |= 0x00000008; // Sets pull down resistor for PA1

    // CCMR!: capture/compare mode register 1
    TIM2->CCMR1 |= 0x0100; // CC2 channel is configured as input, IC2 is mapped on TI2

    // SMCR: Slave Mode control register
    TIM2->SMCR |= 0x0007; // Bits[2:0]  111: External Clock Mode 1 - Rising edges of the selected trigger clock the counter.
    TIM2->SMCR |= 0x0060; // Bits[6:4] 110: selected Trigger: Filtered Timer Input 2 (TI2FP2)

    TIM2->ARR = 0xFFFF; // Set the timer reset on the highest possible value

    TIM2->CR1 |= 0x0001; //0001 Enable Timer
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: This problem looks more like an electronic one than a programming one, so I find it off-topic for Stack Overflow. Both the question and the present answer look well-structured, so I'm voting not to close it but to migrate it to [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital input cannot "trigger" at particular voltage set by the programmers level. But you can use it in the analog mode using `ADC` "analogue watchdog" mode.

If your micro has a built in comparator (many STM32Fxxxxs have one) you can use it to set the "trigger" voltage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no built in comparator in the smt32f4-discovery board. Is an ADC normally not too sensitive for counting single pulses. There are also sometimes 0.5 V peaks in my signal which should not be counted ?. (I'm really new to embedded programming, sry if some questions are really trivial)

Comment: if your micro does not have cmplarators and your signal is rubbish you need some external circuity (LPF + comparator) for this task. You can also read congnopusly ADC and perform the filtering in software but of course it will be much slower

Comment: Ok, thanks for you help. Even if it is not working know, your answers saved me a lot of time.